# How to differentiate Map and string value in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a variable which has 2 types either string or Map. I want to check whether the variable is in type of string or Map. For that I have used the following code.

```
// description is like this description: string | Map<string, string>
if (description instanceof String) {
    return description;
}else {
  return description?.get('test');
}
```

But it gives me the following error.

> Property 'get' does not exist on type 'string | Map'.
>    Property 'get' does not exist on type 'string'

Please help me to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried writing: (description as Map<string, string>).get('test')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceOf String` will not do the right thing, but `typeof description === 'string'` will, or alternatively reverse it and use `instanceof Map`. Not every string is a `String` object. Most aren't.